# TikTok upload video endpoint not working anymore - 400 error

Tags: tiktok, tiktok-api

I've been using the endpoint to upload videos to TikTok for 2 months and it was working fine, but last week it suddenly stopped working. Even the example they have in the docs doesn't work for me anymore:

```
curl --location 'https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/post/publish/inbox/video/init/' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer act.example12345Example12345Example' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8'
--data '{
    "source_info": {
        "source": "FILE_UPLOAD",
        "video_size": 50000123,
        "chunk_size" : 10000000,
        "total_chunk_count": 5
    }
}'
```

I got this error:

```
{
    "data": {},
    "error": {
        "code": "invalid_params",
        "message": "Invalid request parameters. Please ensure there are no unnecessary parameters in query or payload.",
        "log_id": "202309051513410161A9087B2E640FFBC2"
    }
}
```

My app has the `Content Posting API` and also the authorization token has the scope `video.upload`.

Did someone face this issue and find a solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you get this resolved?
I've been trying to solve this, but I've tried top to bottom, and just couldn't see anything wrong. It was working for us until a couple of days ago. Do you have any idea if this is part of the API their removing on September 10?

Comment: No, I have not got this resolved. I opened a support ticket for one week, but no replies yet. And I dont know if this is being remove, but I hope not. 

It's super frustrating, as my product is heavily focused on the TikTok posting feature and the API is so poorly maintained.

Comment: Same here. The direct posting has also been very unstable these past few days.

Comment: it's magically working again, I think tiktok fix on their side. let's see for how long...

Comment: Hi @KarineValença, I am experiencing the same issue. Is it currently working for you?

Comment: Yes, it's working here.